# Instrumental Variable Polynomial Regression

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, econometrics, instrumental-variables, polynomial

Consider the following polynomial regression:

$y_t = b_0 + b_1x_t + b_2x^2_t + e_t$

where $x_t$ is endogenous but there is an instrument that satisfies $Cov(z_t, x_t,)\ne0$ and $Cov(z_t, e_t)=0$.

What would the first and second stage regressions look like given the inclusion of $x_t$ and $x^2_t$?

Comment: Are you asking whether these assumptions are strong enough to justify $(z_t, z_t^2)$ as an instrument for $(x_t, x_t^2)$? If yes, the answer is no (for example instrument relevance cannot work with binary $z_t$).

Comment: My instrument is indeed binary. Could I not estimate two first stages: (i) $x_t=c_0+c_1z_t+c_2x_t^2+u_t$ and (ii) $x_t^2=d_0+d_1z_t+d_2x_t+v_t$ and use fitted values for $x_t$ and $x_t^2$?

Comment: I don't see how this would make sense. It might be easier to think about this in a GMM framework which is better for figuring out identification.